# Multiple pin drop on map in iphone aap

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I am doing this code for multiple pin drop on Mapview.

```
- (void)geocode
{
    NSArray *arrCityName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Baroda", @"Surat", @"Ahmedabad", @"Rajkot", @"Junagadh", @"Mumbai", @"Mehsana", @"Veraval", @"Surendranagar", @"Gondal", nil];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];

    [_mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [_mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [_mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [_mapView setDelegate:self];

    for (int i = 0; i < [arrCityName count]; i++)
    {
        coordinate = [self geoCodeUsingAddress:[arrCityName objectAtIndex:i]];

        NSLog(@"Lat: %f --- Long: %f --- for city:--> %@",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude,[arrCityName objectAtIndex:i]);

        region.center.latitude = latitude;
        region.center.longitude = longitude;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 1.8;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 1.8;

        [_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

        ann.title = [arrCityName objectAtIndex:i];
        ann.coordinate = region.center;
        [_mapView addAnnotation:ann];
    }
}

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) geoCodeUsingAddress:(NSString *)address
{
    latitude = 0, longitude = 0;
    NSString *esc_addr =  [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:req] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    if (result) {
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:result];
        if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil]) {
            [scanner scanDouble:&latitude];
            if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil]) {
                [scanner scanDouble:&longitude];
            }
        }
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = latitude;
    center.longitude = longitude;
    return center;
}
```

Here issue is only that it is giving only last pin drop. I want to multiple pin drop as per the array value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue when i tried to add multiple pins. What i did was : set a global counter to increase by one on every annotation added i.e. on addAnnotaion. Create another function of the for loop :

```
coordinate = [self geoCodeUsingAddress:[arrCityName objectAtIndex:i]];

    NSLog(@"Lat: %f --- Long: %f --- for city:--> %@",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude,[arrCityName objectAtIndex:i]);

    region.center.latitude = latitude;
    region.center.longitude = longitude;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 1.8;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 1.8;

    [_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    ann.title = [arrCityName objectAtIndex:i];
    ann.coordinate = region.center;
    [_mapView addAnnotation:ann];
```

and call that function till the count reaches arrCityName's count

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
static NSString *identifier = @"CarLocation";
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapViewAnnotation class]]) {



    static NSString *AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    if (!pinView)
    {
        pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    UIImageView *leftCalloutView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                                    initWithImage:((MapViewAnnotation *)annotation).imagePin];
    pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftCalloutView;
    pinView.image = leftCalloutView.image;
    [leftCalloutView release];
    [self performSelector:@selector(intermediate) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.05];


    return pinView;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @ScarletWitch for answer....By change like this I got solution for my question.

```
- (void)geocode
{    
    NSArray *arrCityName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Baroda", @"Surat", @"Ahmedabad", @"Rajkot", @"Junagadh", @"Mumbai", @"Mehsana", @"Veraval", @"Surendranagar", @"Gondal", nil];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    MKCoordinateRegion region;

    [_mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [_mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [_mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [_mapView setDelegate:self];

    NSMutableArray *arrPins = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [arrCityName count]; i++)
    {
        coordinate = [self geoCodeUsingAddress:[arrCityName objectAtIndex:i]];

        NSLog(@"Lat: %f --- Long: %f --- for city:--> %@",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude,[arrCityName objectAtIndex:i]);

        region.center.latitude = latitude;
        region.center.longitude = longitude;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 1.8;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 1.8;

        [_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

        DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];

        ann.title = [arrCityName objectAtIndex:i];
        ann.subtitle = @"city";
        ann.imageCity = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h@2x.png"];
        ann.coordinate = region.center;

        [arrPins addObject:ann];

        [_mapView addAnnotations:arrPins];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In  your code your are allocating the DisplayMap (Annotation) only once outside the "for"
loops that is the reason it is holding the last value rather then adding multiple
annotations . Correct your code by allocation the instance within the loop . Also you 
are not required to set the MKCoordinateRegion again and again . You can set this once 
in such a that it contains all the annotation to be shown on to the MapView.

```
    -(void)geocode
    {
       NSArray *arrCityName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Baroda", @"Surat", @"Ahmedabad",   
                               @"Rajkot", @"Junagadh", @"Mumbai", @"Mehsana", @"Veraval", 
                               @"Surendranagar", @"Gondal", nil];

       CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
       MKCoordinateRegion region;

       [_mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
       [_mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
       [_mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
       [_mapView setDelegate:self];

       region.center.latitude = latitude;
       region.center.longitude = longitude;
       region.span.longitudeDelta = 1.8;
       region.span.latitudeDelta = 1.8;

       [_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

       for (int i =0 ; i<[arrCityName count] ; i++)
           {
                DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];

                coordinate = [self geoCodeUsingAddress:[arrCityName objectAtIndex:i]];
                ann.title = [arrCityName objectAtIndex:i];
                ann.coordinate = region.center;
                [_mapView addAnnotation:ann];

            }
      }
```